# Get and post in the same Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, post, get

I have a doubt, in my code I need to work with a get and a post method because in the get I pass some info of one page using Window.open, and in the post I return the value of some field that I obtain with my ETXjs code.

First of all I receive the field that I obtain with my get method, and later the fields where I work in the EXTjs, then when I work with that field to do a consult I need to use the param obtained by get.

Is it possible to do something? This is my code:

```
@WebServlet("/ServletTipoPapel")
public class ServletTipoPapel extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ServletTipoPapel() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //Here i work with my get param Usuario.
        String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "El usuario que usa esto es " + usuario );
        tratarPeticionesEntrantes(request,response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tratarPeticionesEntrantes(request,response);
    }

    private void tratarPeticionesEntrantes(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(request.getParameter("Funcionalidad")==null || request.getParameter("Funcionaldiad")==""){
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/PantallasGestion/tipoPapel.jsp");
            rd.forward(request,response);
        }else{
            JSONObject json=tratarPeticion(request);
            System.out.println(json.toJSONString());
            PrintWriter escritorRespuesta=response.getWriter();
            escritorRespuesta.println(json.toJSONString());
            //escritorRespuesta.println();
            escritorRespuesta.flush();
            escritorRespuesta.close();
        }
    }

    //JSON

    private JSONObject tratarPeticion(HttpServletRequest request){
        JSONObject respuesta=null;
        String parametroFuncionalidad=request.getParameter("Funcionalidad");
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("Funcionalidad"));

        if(parametroFuncionalidad!=null && parametroFuncionalidad!=""){
            if(parametroFuncionalidad.equalsIgnoreCase("CONSULTA")){
                respuesta=tratarPeticionConsulta(request);
            }else if(parametroFuncionalidad.equalsIgnoreCase("MODIFICAR")){
                respuesta=tratarPeticionModificacion(request);
            }else if(parametroFuncionalidad.equalsIgnoreCase("INSERTAR")){
                respuesta=tratarPeticionAlta(request);
                System.out.println("aqui entra");
            }else if(parametroFuncionalidad.equalsIgnoreCase("ELIMINAR")){
                respuesta=tratarPeticionBaja(request);  
            }else{
            }
        }
        return respuesta;
    }

    private JSONArray tipoPapelesToArray(ArrayList<TipoPapel> papeles){
        JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
        for(int i=0;i<papeles.size();i++){
            JSONObject elemento1=new JSONObject();
            elemento1.put("TIPPAP",papeles.get(i).getTipoPapel());
            elemento1.put("TAMPAP",papeles.get(i).getTamanioPapel());
            elemento1.put("INDPAR",papeles.get(i).getIndicadorCanal());
            elemento1.put("NUMOPTDO",papeles.get(i).getNumOptimoPaginas());
            elemento1.put("INDCAR",papeles.get(i).getIndicadorCaratula());
            elemento1.put("FORCAR",papeles.get(i).getFormularioCaratula());
            elemento1.put("VERCAR",papeles.get(i).getVersionCaratula());
            elemento1.put("FORSEPIN",papeles.get(i).getFormularioSeparadorInicial());
            elemento1.put("VERSEPIN",papeles.get(i).getVersionSeparadorInicial());
            elemento1.put("FORSEPFI",papeles.get(i).getFormularioSeparadorFinal());
            elemento1.put("VERSEPFI",papeles.get(i).getVersionSeparadorFinal());
            elemento1.put("NUMFICSP",papeles.get(i).getFicheroSpool());
            elemento1.put("DESTIPPA",papeles.get(i).getDescripcionTipoPapel());
            elemento1.put("TIP_TRABAJO",papeles.get(i).getTipoTrabajo());
            elemento1.put("FECALT",papeles.get(i).getFechaAlta());
            elemento1.put("FECMOD",papeles.get(i).getFechaModificacion());
            elemento1.put("TERMOD",papeles.get(i).getUsuarioModificacion());
            elemento1.put("HORMOD",papeles.get(i).getHoraModificacion());
            list.add(elemento1);
        }
        return list;
    }

    //PARTE DE ALTA

    private JSONObject tratarPeticionAlta(HttpServletRequest request){
        System.out.println("aqui tambien");
        TipoPapelDAO papelDAO=new TipoPapelDAO();
        String [] camposAObtener={"TODOS"};
        String entorno="DESARROLLO";
        ArrayList<TipoPapel> papeles=papelDAO.obtenerParaAlta(obtenerCamposParaAlta(request),entorno);
        //System.out.println("aqui tambien despues 2");
        JSONObject respuesta = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray list = tipoPapelesToArray(papeles);
        respuesta.put("TiposPapel",list);
        //System.out.println("aqui tambien despues 3" + respuesta);
        return respuesta;
    }

    private String[] obtenerCamposParaAlta(HttpServletRequest request){
        ArrayList<String> elementosAux=new ArrayList<String>();
        int contador1 = 0;
        int contador2 = 0;
        int contador3 = 0;
        int contador4 = 0;
        int contador5 = 0;
        int contador6 = 0;
        int contador7 = 0;
        int contador8 = 0;
        int contador9 = 0;
        int contador10 = 0;
        int contador11 = 0;
        int contador12 = 0;
        int contador13 = 0;
        int contador14 = 0;

        if(request.getParameter("DPTipoPapel")!=null && request.getParameter("DPTipoPapel").trim()!="")
        {
            elementosAux.add("TIPPAP~"+request.getParameter("DPTipoPapel"));
            contador1 = 1;
        }
        if (contador1==0)
        {
            elementosAux.add("TIPPAP~NULL");
        }

        if(request.getParameter("DPTamPapel")!=null && request.getParameter("DPTamPapel").trim()!="")
        {
            elementosAux.add("TAMPAP~"+request.getParameter("DPTamPapel"));
            contador6 = 1;
        }
        if (contador6==0)
        {
            elementosAux.add("TAMPAP~NULL");
        }

        if(request.getParameter("DPIndicadorSoD")!=null && request.getParameter("DPIndicadorSoD").trim()!="")
        {
            elementosAux.add("INDPAR~"+request.getParameter("DPIndicadorSoD"));
            contador2 = 1;
        }
        if (contador2==0)
        {
            elementosAux.add("INDPAR~NULL");
        }

        if(request.getParameter("DPNumOptimo")!=null && request.getParameter("DPNumOptimo").trim()!="")
        {
            elementosAux.add("NUMOPTDO~"+request.getParameter("DPNumOptimo"));
            contador7 = 1;
        }
        if (contador7==0)
        {
            elementosAux.add("NUMOPTDO~NULL");
        }

        if(request.getParameter("DPCaratula")!=null && request.getParameter("DPCaratula").trim()!="")
        {
            elementosAux.add("INDCAR~"+request.getParameter("DPCaratula"));
            contador3 = 1;
        }
        if (contador3==0)
        {
            elementosAux.add("INDCAR~NULL");
        }

        if(request.getParameter("DPFormularioCaratula")!=null && request.getParameter("DPFormularioCaratula").trim()!="")
        {
            elementosAux.add("FORCAR~"+request.getParameter("DPFormularioCaratula"));
            contador8 = 1;
        }
        if (contador8==0)
        {
            elementosAux.add("FORCAR~NULL");
        }

        if(request.getParameter("DPVersCaratula")!=null && request.getParameter("DPVersCaratula").trim()!="")
        {
            elementosAux.add("VERCAR~"+request.getParameter("DPVersCaratula"));
            contador4 = 1;
        }
        if (contador4==0)
        {
            elementosAux.add("VERCAR~NULL");
        }

        if(request.getParameter("DPFinicial")!=null && request.getParameter("DPFinicial").trim()!="")
        {
                elementosAux.add("FORSEPIN~"+request.getParameter("DPFinicial"));
                contador10=1;
        }
        if (contador10==0)
        {
            elementosAux.add("FORSEPIN~NULL");
        }

        if(request.getParameter("DPVinicial")!=null && request.getParameter("DPVinicial").trim()!="")
        {
            elementosAux.add("VERSEPIN~"+request.getParameter("DPVinicial"));
            contador11=1;
        }
        if (contador11==0)
        {
            elementosAux.add("VERSEPIN~NULL");
        }

        if(request.getParameter("DPFfinal")!=null && request.getParameter("DPFfinal").trim()!="")
        {
            elementosAux.add("FORSEPFI~"+request.getParameter("DPFfinal"));
            contador12=1;
        }
        if (contador12==0)
        {
            elementosAux.add("FORSEPFI~NULL");
        }

        if(request.getParameter("DPVfinal")!=null && request.getParameter("DPVfinal").trim()!="")
        {
            elementosAux.add("VERSEPFI~"+request.getParameter("DPVfinal"));
            contador13=1;
        }
        if (contador13==0)
        {
            elementosAux.add("VERSEPFI~NULL");
        }

        if(request.getParameter("DPSpool")!=null && request.getParameter("DPSpool").trim()!="")
        {
            elementosAux.add("NUMFICSP~"+request.getParameter("DPSpool"));
            contador5 = 1;
        }
        if (contador5==0)
        {
            elementosAux.add("NUMFICSP~NULL");
        }

        if(request.getParameter("DPDescripcion")!=null && request.getParameter("DPDescripcion").trim()!="")
        {
            elementosAux.add("DESTIPPA~"+request.getParameter("DPDescripcion"));
            contador9 = 1;
        }
        if (contador9==0)
        {
            elementosAux.add("DESTIPPA~NULL");
        }

        if(request.getParameter("DPTipoTrabajo")!=null && request.getParameter("DPTipoTrabajo").trim()!="")
        {
            elementosAux.add("TIP_TRABAJO~"+request.getParameter("DPTipoTrabajo"));
            contador14 = 1;
        }
        if (contador14==0)
        {
            elementosAux.add("TIP_TRABAJO~NULL");
        }

        //Here i must work with USUARIO because when i update a register i need to put the value of the user that do that action
        String [] elementos=new String[elementosAux.size()];
        return elementosAux.toArray(elementos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to execute the same code for GET and POST or do you want to execute the POST from GET ? What exactly you want ?

Comment: Can you please rephrase your questions some what fishy.

Comment: i execute the two, first the get and later the post... that the problem, i must pase i var that i obtein by get to a array where i put vars obtein by post

Comment: You can POST the value right ?

Comment: yes i dont have any problem wiht my post method, my problem is when i try to pass the GET value... i obtein the value correct in some class but i dont know to pass to the same array that the array that i use for my POST vars.

Comment: Are you trying to POST and GET at the same time?

Comment: First the get, obtein a value and use that value when i must do a consult in a DDBB where i use the values that i obtein with my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can have a servlet do different things depending on the http method used to call it (get, post, etc.) but it quickly leads to confusion and you're usually better off using separate servlets for each, and maybe having them all respond in kind to both methods if so desired.

What you can NOT do is go back from the server to the client and back again to the servlet within the context of a single request.

If that doesn't clarify your confusion you will have to read up some more on servlets and http communication in general.

Comment: The problem is the logic that i must use, i have my application insert in a web portal where i only can obtein the name of the user who use the app using method get and call then to my servlet with window.open, later when my servlet is open in that momento call to my EXTjs, where i can do some operation with an oracle database, and in this part i obtein the fields that i need to consult, erase, chagened.. using a method post. Then my problem is that, i need that in the part of my code where i do the update i could use the user that i have obtein first...

Comment: @Deckard27 just because you want to do something in a specific way doesn't make it suddenly possible. You'll have to find a way to make things work within the limits of http. Like having the client do 2 calls to your servlet before displaying the results....

Answer (score 0):

can I define both doGet ans doPost  ?

Yes

Can I Call both at once from one single request from browser

No

one thing if I get your problem correct is : make an ajax call from your page which will make post call to your sevlet

but before we can suggest something very precise , be clear on your question , what and when do you want to do with your request

Comment: I call him from to request from browser, one in the web page that i dont controle and one my app. My app is in a web page where in a js i call to my servlet (passing with get a var), then my servlet launch a EXTjs what is a form to do consult in a database, my problem is that the var that i return with get is used to log the user that do changes in the database.

Comment: Perhaps i have think to use a window open modificied to obtein the var in POST mode...

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to pass the var to my jsp :

```
              protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)         throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "El usuario que usa esto es " + usuario );

    request.setAttribute("usuario",usuario);
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/PantallasGestion/tipoPapel.jsp");
    rd.forward(request,response);
}
```

Then in my jsp i call my EXTjs where the return values will call to my POST method in my servlet, i have now only the problem that i dont know how to pass one value from a jsp to a js(EXTJS)... is possible that i call directly my EXTjs and dont use jsp?